# Angular 2, chunk for children routes not createds if create array of children befor Routes object

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

My children routes works good when create them like:

```
let routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'a', loadChildren: '../+a/a.module.ts#AModule', canLoad: [AGuard]},
            {path: 'b', loadChildren: '../+b/b.module.ts#BModule', canLoad: [BGuard]}
        ]
    }
];
```

and chunks created for all modules, when i try init children before like this, all stop working, and i don t have chunks for this modules:

```
let children: Routes = [];

children.push({path: 'a', loadChildren: '../+a/a.module.ts#AModule', canLoad: [AGuard]})
children.push({path: 'b', loadChildren: '../+b/b.module.ts#BModule', canLoad: [BGuard]})

let routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: children
    }
];
```

And this very strange, i think this is the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result i create 2 environment files 1st environment.a.ts has route a

```
export const environment = {
    ....
    {path: 'a', loadChildren: '../+a/a.module.ts#AModule', canLoad: [AGuard]}
}
```

and second environment.b.ts has route b

```
export const environment = {
    ....
    {path: 'b', loadChildren: '../+b/b.module.ts#BModule', canLoad: [BGuard]}
}
```

after that i can use my routes like:

```
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
let routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: environment.routes
    }
];
```

and chunks normal creats

Answer (score 0):

Try with define children as a generic array instead type Router.

```
let children:any = [];

children.push({path: 'a', loadChildren: '../+a/a.module.ts#AModule', canLoad: [AGuard]})
children.push({path: 'b', loadChildren: '../+b/b.module.ts#BModule', canLoad: [BGuard]})

let routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: children
    }
];
```